# element.checked problem with if statement

Tags: javascript, html

Hi guys i am making calculator app and i have got a problem. I made 3 radio buttons and want them to be checked with 'if statement' in JS file. It just does not work at all because 'main' does not get any class when input2 or 3 is clicked. Only the first one makes 'main' getting it but thats because of input1.checked is defaultly set to true (becaue i want the app to have a theme 1 at the start of the page). Can anyone help me, pls?

Here is the link to the project on my github:

```js
function setColorTheme() {
  let main = document.getElementById("main");
  let input1 = document.getElementById("input1");
  let input2 = document.getElementById("input2");
  let input3 = document.getElementById("input3");

  input1.checked = true;

  if (input1.checked == true) {
    main.classList.add("dark");
    console.log("hello");
  } else {
    main.classList.remove("dark");
  }
  if (input2.checked == true) {
    main.classList.add("light");
    console.log("hello2");
  } else {
    main.classList.remove("light");
  }
  if (input3.checked == true) {
    main.classList.add("saturated");
    console.log("hello3");
  } else {
    main.classList.remove("saturated");
  }

  console.log(main);
  console.log(input1);
}

setColorTheme();
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Spartan", sans-serif;
}

main {
  background: #3a4764;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: white;
}

.calc-container {
  min-height: 55vh;
  width: 28%;
}
.calc-container header {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 10vh;
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.calc-container header .theme-toggler {
  display: flex;
}
.calc-container header .theme-toggler h2 {
  font-size: 12px;
  align-self: flex-end;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}
.calc-container header .theme-toggler .label-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  text-align: center;
}
.calc-container header .theme-toggler .label-container .label {
  margin: 0rem 0.35rem;
}
.calc-container header .theme-toggler .input-container {
  width: 60px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #232c43;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}
.calc-container header .theme-toggler .input-container .input {
  appearance: none;
  background: #d03f2f;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.calc-container header .theme-toggler .input-container .input:checked {
  opacity: 1;
}
.calc-container .screen {
  min-height: 10vh;
  width: 90%;
  background: #182034;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.calc-container .button-container {
  min-height: 40vh;
  width: 90%;
  background: #232c43;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 1rem auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  padding: 1.5rem;
  grid-gap: 1rem;
}
.calc-container .button-container .button,
.calc-container .button-container .reset,
.calc-container .button-container .equal,
.calc-container .button-container .delete {
  border-radius: 10px;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #eae3dc;
  box-shadow: 0 5px #b4a597;
  text-align: center;
}
.calc-container .button-container .reset,
.calc-container .button-container .delete {
  background: #637097;
  box-shadow: 0 5px #404e72;
}
.calc-container .button-container .equal {
  background: #d03f2f;
  box-shadow: 0 5px #93261a;
}
.calc-container .button-container .reset,
.calc-container .button-container .equal,
.calc-container .button-container .delete {
  color: white;
}
.calc-container .button-container .button {
  color: #444b5a;
}
.calc-container .button-container .reset {
  grid-column: 1/3;
}
.calc-container .button-container .equal {
  grid-column: 3/5;
}

/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link
      rel="icon"
      type="image/png"
      sizes="32x32"
      href="./images/favicon-32x32.png"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Spartan:wght@700&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />

    <script src="./script.js" defer></script>
    <title>Frontend Mentor | Calculator app</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <main id="main">
      <div class="calc-container">
        <header>
          <h1>calc</h1>

          <div class="theme-toggler">
            <h2>THEME</h2>

            <div>
              <div class="label-container">
                <label for="input1" class="label">1</label>
                <label for="input2" class="label">2</label>
                <label for="input3" class="label">3</label>
              </div>
              <div class="input-container">
                <input id="input1" class="input" type="radio" name="theme" />
                <input id="input2" class="input" type="radio" name="theme" />
                <input id="input3" class="input" type="radio" name="theme" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </header>

        <div class="screen">
          <div class="screen-one">3232</div>
          <div class="screen-two">dsa</div>
        </div>
        <div class="button-container">
          <button class="button">7</button>
          <button class="button">8</button>
          <button class="button">9</button>
          <button class="delete">DEL</button>
          <button class="button">4</button>
          <button class="button">5</button>
          <button class="button">6</button>
          <button class="button">+</button>
          <button class="button">1</button>
          <button class="button">2</button>
          <button class="button">3</button>
          <button class="button">-</button>
          <button class="button">.</button>
          <button class="button">0</button>
          <button class="button">/</button>
          <button class="button">X</button>
          <button class="reset">RESET</button>
          <button class="equal">=</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>

    <!-- <script src="./script.js"></script> -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is live site of it: https://adrian397.github.io/frontEndMentorChallenges/calculator-app-main/index.html

[js file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjO3t.png)

[html file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbM61.png)

Comment: Just a side note - you don't need to add an event listener for DOMContentLoaded when the script already has the `defer` attribute.

Comment: @Spectric Actually ye i had this in my project but it was changed before the project was being pushed to the repository like 15mins ago. It looks like github live page is kinda bugged because it didnt update the code from the repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the radio inputs with `document.querySelectorAll('input[name="theme"]')`, loop through them with `forEach()` and add an event listener for `change`.

```js
let input1 = document.getElementById("input1");
let input2 = document.getElementById("input2");
let input3 = document.getElementById("input3");
input1.checked = true;

function setColorTheme() {
  let main = document.getElementById("main");



  if (input1.checked == true) {
    main.classList.add("dark");
    console.log("hello");
  } else {
    main.classList.remove("dark");
  }
  if (input2.checked == true) {
    main.classList.add("light");
    console.log("hello2");
  } else {
    main.classList.remove("light");
  }
  if (input3.checked == true) {
    main.classList.add("saturated");
    console.log("hello3");
  } else {
    main.classList.remove("saturated");
  }

  console.log(main);
  console.log(input1);
}

setColorTheme();

document.querySelectorAll('input[name="theme"]').forEach((e)=>{
    e.addEventListener("change", setColorTheme);
})
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Spartan", sans-serif;
}

main {
  background: #3a4764;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: white;
}

.calc-container {
  min-height: 55vh;
  width: 28%;
}

.calc-container header {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 10vh;
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.calc-container header .theme-toggler {
  display: flex;
}

.calc-container header .theme-toggler h2 {
  font-size: 12px;
  align-self: flex-end;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

.calc-container header .theme-toggler .label-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  text-align: center;
}

.calc-container header .theme-toggler .label-container .label {
  margin: 0rem 0.35rem;
}

.calc-container header .theme-toggler .input-container {
  width: 60px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #232c43;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.calc-container header .theme-toggler .input-container .input {
  appearance: none;
  background: #d03f2f;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.calc-container header .theme-toggler .input-container .input:checked {
  opacity: 1;
}

.calc-container .screen {
  min-height: 10vh;
  width: 90%;
  background: #182034;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.calc-container .button-container {
  min-height: 40vh;
  width: 90%;
  background: #232c43;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 1rem auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  padding: 1.5rem;
  grid-gap: 1rem;
}

.calc-container .button-container .button,
.calc-container .button-container .reset,
.calc-container .button-container .equal,
.calc-container .button-container .delete {
  border-radius: 10px;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #eae3dc;
  box-shadow: 0 5px #b4a597;
  text-align: center;
}

.calc-container .button-container .reset,
.calc-container .button-container .delete {
  background: #637097;
  box-shadow: 0 5px #404e72;
}

.calc-container .button-container .equal {
  background: #d03f2f;
  box-shadow: 0 5px #93261a;
}

.calc-container .button-container .reset,
.calc-container .button-container .equal,
.calc-container .button-container .delete {
  color: white;
}

.calc-container .button-container .button {
  color: #444b5a;
}

.calc-container .button-container .reset {
  grid-column: 1/3;
}

.calc-container .button-container .equal {
  grid-column: 3/5;
}


/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="./images/favicon-32x32.png" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css" />
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Spartan:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />

  <script src="./script.js" defer></script>
  <title>Frontend Mentor | Calculator app</title>
</head>

<body>
  <main id="main">
    <div class="calc-container">
      <header>
        <h1>calc</h1>

        <div class="theme-toggler">
          <h2>THEME</h2>

          <div>
            <div class="label-container">
              <label for="input1" class="label">1</label>
              <label for="input2" class="label">2</label>
              <label for="input3" class="label">3</label>
            </div>
            <div class="input-container">
              <input id="input1" class="input" type="radio" name="theme" />
              <input id="input2" class="input" type="radio" name="theme" />
              <input id="input3" class="input" type="radio" name="theme" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </header>

      <div class="screen">
        <div class="screen-one">3232</div>
        <div class="screen-two">dsa</div>
      </div>
      <div class="button-container">
        <button class="button">7</button>
        <button class="button">8</button>
        <button class="button">9</button>
        <button class="delete">DEL</button>
        <button class="button">4</button>
        <button class="button">5</button>
        <button class="button">6</button>
        <button class="button">+</button>
        <button class="button">1</button>
        <button class="button">2</button>
        <button class="button">3</button>
        <button class="button">-</button>
        <button class="button">.</button>
        <button class="button">0</button>
        <button class="button">/</button>
        <button class="button">X</button>
        <button class="reset">RESET</button>
        <button class="equal">=</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>

  <!-- <script src="./script.js"></script> -->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked! But i have got one question. Shouldnt function setColorTheme not see inputs? They are declared with 'let' and from i know let is block-scoped declariation and they are placed outside of a function.

Comment: @Adrian It's declared outside of all functions or curly braces, so it exists in the global scope.

Comment: You mean function that is invoked in global scope so it see those let variables on the top, right? Sorry for asking but im still learning and want everything to be clear for me.

Comment: @Adrian Precisely, yes.

Comment: Thanks, a lot !

Comment: @Adrian Glad to help :)